# Day 8: Dictionaries and Maps

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, dictionary

I am trying to solve the problem with looping through ah huge number (100000 elements )array but it's not successful on huge number although it works on small number array, I tried many solutions but not of them passed when submitting mu answer
the task is

Task
Given names and phone numbers, assemble a phone book that maps friends' names to their respective phone numbers. You will then be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for. For each query, print the associated entry from your phone book on a new line in the form name=phoneNumber; if an entry for  is not found,

**Sample Input**

3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry

**Sample Output**

sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933

[here is a link to the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/problem)

here is my solution

```
    async function processData(input) {
  let initialarr = input.split("\n");
  let i, j, len2, len;
  len = parseInt(initialarr[0]);
  j = parseInt(initialarr[0]) + 1;
  len2 = initialarr.length;

  searchArr();
  function searchArr() {
    while (j < len2) {
      checkForname(initialarr[j]);
      j++;
    }
  }

  function checkForname(num) {
    i = 1;

    while (i <= len) {
      if (initialarr[i].split(" ")[0].trim() == num.trim()) {
        console.log(
          initialarr[i].split(" ")[0] + "=" + initialarr[i].split(" ")[1]
        );

        return;
      }

      i++;
    }

    console.log("Not found ");
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: It appears the point of the exercise is to use a Map or Dictionary.  Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map.  That is, rather than using an array to store the names and numbers, use a Map object.  With an array, finding the name in an unsorted list involves a linear search of the array, so the larger the array, the longer it will take to find the value.  Whereas with a Map, finding a name (ie, Map key) is a direct hash lookup of the key/value pair, so generally speaking, increasing the number of entries has little effect.